# deploy Soap service on Liberty

Tags: java, soap, deployment, websphere-liberty

I am trying to migrate my application from WebSphere to Liberty.
When i call my Service from SoapUI i get the following message in the Liberty console:

> [WARNING ] SRVE0190E: File not found: xxxws

(xxxws being the endpoint).
When i try to access the wsdl file with my browser i get the same error code:

> [WARNING ] SRVE0190E: File not found: xxxws/WEB-INF/wsdl/yyy.wsdl

On startup i can see what Features are enabled:

> [AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [jsp-2.3, jsf-2.2, servlet-3.1, ssl-1.0, jndi-1.0, jaxws-2.2, localConnector-1.0, appSecurity-2.0, jdbc-4.1, jaxrs-2.0, restConnector-1.0, jaxrsClient-2.0, el-3.0, jaxb-2.2, json-1.0, adminCenter-1.0, distributedMap-1.0].

I think servlet and jaxws should be the relevant ones. Are there any missing? Is there a different reason i get These file not found messages?

When i use a different context-root in my URL i get a different error message (context-root not found). So at least the context root seems to be right.

When i call my webservice from SoapUI i see that my StartupServlet is running and doing all kinds of initializations including database queries.

Here is the relevant stuff from the web.xml:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>StartupServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>foo.bar.StartupServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>10</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>FooBarWebServiceInterface</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>foo.bar.webservice.impl.FooBarIWebServiceInterfaceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>StartupServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/StartupServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>FooBarWebServiceInterface</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/xxxws</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I feel like i am missing something simple, any ideas?

Thanks!